# How can I make a macro dynamic in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dynamic

I've been trying to create a dynamic macro that copies the previous row and pastes it in the actual one. I've been able to create it, and it runs each time that I change the sheet (on change trigger). Until then, everything is fine.

The thing is that I'm only able to do it for a specific row, i.e., I've created it for row 11, however, once that it has run in row 11, I want it to work for row 12, once that row 12 is fulfilled, then it goes to row 13, and so on.

This is what I have now:

```js
function copyandnumber() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L11').offset(-1, 0, 1, 25).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('L11'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Do you know how to change this 11 by something dynamic, for it to work on every row?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function copyandnumber() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L'+lastRow).offset(-1, 0, 1, 25).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('L'+lastRow), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Comment: Yes! It is working now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool ! but you do not have to thank ... just upvote il you agree and close, so that the answer will appear for further query